# Java применение concat в функции

Tags: java

День добрый, вопрос следующий. Вот есть такой код:

```
     public String toString()
    {
        String text ="sss";
        text.concat("dss");
        return text;
    }
```

и concat не будет исполняться, IDE'шка информирует по этому поводу следующим образом:

> Reports any calls to specific methods where the result of that call is ignored. Both methods specified in the inspection's settings and methods annotated with org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract(pure=true) are checked. For many methods, ignoring the result is perfectly legitimate, but for some methods it is almost certainly an error. Examples of methods where ignoring the result of a call is likely to be an error include java.io.inputStream.read(), which returns the number of bytes actually read, any method on java.lang.String or java.math.BigInteger, as all of those methods are side-effect free and thus pointless if ignored.

Так вот, кто-то может пояснить в связи с чем все так идет и как такое не ловить?

Comment: Думаю все просто , вся проблема в том что должно быть `text=text.concat("dss");`? ( concat не изменяет переменную?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Класс [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) является [иммутабельным классом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning)(зачем это сделано смотреть [тут](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/why-string-is-immutable-in-java/)), т.е. после создания экземпляра можно только пересоздать его, но не изменить значения внутри. Соответственно метод 
[concat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) не изменяет значения в `text`, а создаёт новый экземпляр класса [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), который у вас никуда не присваивается и пропадает в пучине GC. Вам надо сделать либо так:

```
public String toString() {
    String text ="sss";
    text = text.concat("dss");
    return text;
}
```

либо вообще так:

```
public String toString() {
    return "sss".concat("dss");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Справедливо предупреждает. Эта строка не имеет смысла. В продакшн коде ей точно не место, а для каких-либо тестовых или игрушечных целей на предупреждение можно не обращать внимания.

Если же вы думаете что после

```
text.concat("dss");
```

строка `text` примет вид `sssdss`, то вы ошибаетесь, строки неизменяемые и `concat` вернет вам такую строку, но не сделает строку `text` таковой.
То есть если вы хотите вернуть из метода `toString` строку `sssdss`, то следует сделать так:

```
public String toString()
{
    String text ="sss";
    return text.concat("dss");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод [concat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) не изменяет строку, а лишь создает новую как результат слияния текущей и переданной в качестве параметра. Метод возвращает новый объект `String`, как раз таки результат конкатенации. Этот результат нужно теперь куда-то сложить.

Поэтому правильно писать либо

```
String text ="sss";
return text.concat("dss");
```

либо если хотите как вы, то

```
String text ="sss";
text = text.concat("dss");
return text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text ="sss";
text = text.concat("dss");
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Зачем дублировать то, что уже есть в ответах, причём с ухудшением качества?

Comment: @asianirish, содержится тут ответ.